# How to get numbers separated by comma entered in a line into an array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, numbers

How could I get values entered in a single line by the user eq: 1, 3, 400, 444, etc.. into an array. I know I must declare a separator in this case the comma ",". Could someone help?

Answer (score 9):

```
String input = "1, 3, 400, 444";
String[] numbers = input.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

You can use much simpler separator in [`String.split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) like `","` but the more complex `"\\s*,\\s*"` additionally strips whitespaces around comma.

Comment: Also if you don't want to use regular expressions use the String.trim() method after using the String.split(",") method.

Comment: @Thihara: well, `","` separator is still a regular expression - just a simpler one.

Comment: I agree. I just thought it best to give a simpler approach because this seem like a beginner question.

Comment: yeah, that seems a good solution, but in my case the input is of type int. In other words I need to collect 1, 3, 3, 4 in a single line, and then parse it and into single numbers...

Answer (score 2):

You want to use [split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

```
userInput.split(",");
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String line = "1, 3, 400, 444";

String[] numbers = line.split(",\\s+");
int[] answer = new int[numbers.length];

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++)
    answer[i] = Integer.parseInt(numbers[i]);
```

Now `answer` is an array with the numbers in the string as integers. The other answers just split the string, if you need actual *numbers* you need to convert them.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(answer));
> [1, 3, 400, 444]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String line = "1, 3, 400, 444";
for(String s : line.split(","))
   System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String input = "1, 3, 400, 444";
String[] numbers = input.split("\\s*,\\s*");
```

It's the right answer, "\\s*,\\s*" is a regular expression, regex is very useful for the string parsing.