# Selecting multiple results from query

Tags: java, sparql, jena

I have this query for example which returns four results. What I am doing with this code is selecting one of those results through an integer, so that I can do another query for it later. What I have been trying to do, and haven't been able to yet, is select more than just one result, so that I can reuse them separately. For example this query would return:

1. RESULT A
2. RESULT B
3. RESULT C
4. RESULT D

I can type, for example, `1` in the console and get that value in a string and reuse it. What is a convenient way, for example, to type `1,2,3` and get these values added to a String array?

```java
public static String[] path = new String[30];

String queryString =
    "PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> " +        
    "PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> " +
    "PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> " +
    "PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> " +
    "PREFIX bio: <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Onto#> " +

    " SELECT DISTINCT ?Animal " +
    " WHERE { ?Animal rdf:type bio:Animal } " ;

Query query = QueryFactory.create(queryString);
QueryExecution qe= QueryExecutionFactory.create(query, model);
ResultSet resultset = qe.execSelect();
ResultSet results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(resultset); 
ResultSet results2 = ResultSetFactory.copyResults(results);
ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query);

List<QuerySolution> e = ResultSetFormatter.toList(results2);
String next;
System.out.println("Select Animal: ");

next = user_input.next( );

int i = Integer.parseInt(next);
QuerySolution e1 = e.get(i);
RDFNode rd = e1.get("");  
String rds = rd.toString();
String phrase = rds; 
String delims = "[#]";
String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims); 
newStr = tokens[1].replaceAll("_","");
path[1] = newStr;
```

#### Edit, updated code:

```java
final Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );          
String selec2;
selec2 = input.next();

final String[] indices = selec2.split("\\s*,\\s*");

final List<QuerySolution> selectedSolutions = new ArrayList<QuerySolution>( indices.length ) {{
        final List<QuerySolution> solutions = ResultSetFormatter.toList( results2 );
        for ( final String index : indices ) {
            add( solutions.get( Integer.valueOf( index )));
        }
    }};

System.out.println( "== Selected Solutions ==" );
System.out.println(selectedSolutions);

int k = 0;
while (input.hasNext()) {
    int i = Integer.parseInt(selec2);
    QuerySolution e1 = selectedSolutions.get(i);

    RDFNode rd = e1.get("Ani");  
    String rds = rd.toString();
    String phrase = rds;  
    String delims = "[#]";
    String[] tokens = phrase.split(delims); 
    newStr = tokens[1].replaceAll("_", "");
    path[k]= newStr;
    k++;
}
System.out.println(path);
```

Comment: This code isn't complete, and it's hard to tell exactly what it is that you're trying to do. It seem likes your `user_input` is being used to select a particular row from the result set (note that without ordering in the SPARQL query, the order of the solutions in the result set is not specified, so you could get different results every time).  I'm also not clear why `e1.get("")` would return anything, since  you can't have variable whose name is `""`.

Comment: Reading this again, I think I understand a bit more clearly.  You want to read a list of integers, and select the the query solutions at those indices in the result set.  Is that correct?

Comment: You are right about e1.get("") it does have a value init "Animal".   So I should change my resultset formatter to a different style? Is there a way to set user_input select more than 1 rows?

Comment: Yes and you are right about your last comment

Comment: Would it be sufficient to simply create a `List<QuerySolution>` and add the appropriate elements from the `List<QuerySolution>` that you extracted from the original `ResultSet`?

Comment: I want the user to be able to see the query results first and then choose which ones to get

Comment: What problem are you running into?  I know that unless you've got a [ResultSetRewindable](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSetRewindable.html), you'll consume the result set the first time that you print it.  Once you've got the indices, do you want a `List<QuerySolution>` or another `ResultSet` with just the selected solutions, or something else?

Comment: a List<QuerySolution>. Problem is I cant find a way to give the user the chance to select more than one results occured from the query. Then I want to store the selections in a string[]

Comment: This sounds more like a Java string processing question than a Jena question, then. There are some other questions on this site that can help with that, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/q/10565335/1281433.

Comment: So there is no need to chaange the resultsetformatter in order to achieve that?

Comment: It's OK to edit your question with updates, but please don't remove the original code.  Removing the original code removes context from the question that would help people find it, and that help the answer make sense.  I've rolled back the edit, and included the updated code in a section clearly labelled as such.

Comment: Ok sorry and thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get a ResultSet, you can only use its solutions once, and then they're consumed.  So, in order to iterate over the solutions multiple times, you need to copy the results using, e.g., [ResultSetFactory.copyResults](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/arq/com/hp/hpl/jena/query/ResultSetFactory.html#copyResults%28com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet%29).  Then you can access the query solutions multiple times.  You can take an input string like `"1,2,3"` and get a string array `["1", "2", "3"]` using something like the answer to

- [how to get numbers separated by comma entered in a line into an array in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10565335/1281433)

Then you can iterate through the indices and select just the query solutions that you want and add them to a list.  For instance:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QueryExecutionFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.QuerySolution;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSet;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.query.ResultSetFormatter;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Model;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;

public class QuerySolutionsFromIndicesExample {

    final static String modelText = "" +
            "@prefix bio: <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Onto#>.\n" +
            "@prefix ex: <http://example.org/>.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "ex:Giraffe a bio:Animal .\n" +
            "ex:Dog a bio:Animal .\n" +
            "ex:Cat a bio:Animal . \n" +
            "ex:WoollyMammoth a bio:Animal.\n" +
            "";

    final static String sparqlQuery = "" +
            "prefix bio: <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Onto#>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "select ?animal where {\n" +
            "  ?animal a bio:Animal\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read( new ByteArrayInputStream( modelText.getBytes()), null, "TTL" );

        final ResultSet results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults( QueryExecutionFactory.create( sparqlQuery, model ).execSelect() );

        System.out.println( "== All Solutions ==" );
        ResultSetFormatter.out( results );

        // based on https://stackoverflow.com/q/10565335/1281433
        final String input = "0,3"; 
        final String[] indices = input.split("\\s*,\\s*");

        final List<QuerySolution> selectedSolutions = new ArrayList<QuerySolution>( indices.length ) {{
            final List<QuerySolution> solutions = ResultSetFormatter.toList( results );
            for ( final String index : indices ) {
                add( solutions.get( Integer.valueOf( index )));
            }
        }};

        System.out.println( "== Selected Solutions ==" );
        System.out.println( selectedSolutions );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats what I was looking for. One last question, do you know how could i print the selected solutions in a format like ResultSetFormatter.out(System.out, results, query) ?

Comment: I replaced string input with scanner so that user can type 1,2 and get the desired selected solutions. I then tried to parse these solutions and add them to a new string[] path, but it wont print results. Updated the code

Comment: OK, for printing the results like the ResultSetFormatter does, I think you want to create another ResultSet, really.  Jena provides a number of methods for creating ResultSets from other ResultSets, (e.g., combining ResultSets), but not for creating a ResultSet from a List<QuerySolution>.  It's not incredibly difficult to implement the ResultSet interface, but it's not entirely trivial either.  I think it's a different enough task that it merits a new question. (Plus, it will get more attention that way.)

Comment: The question about how to get input from a user and split it into an array of integer indices is really a separate question, and one that's probably been answered elsewhere.

Comment: here is the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18850064/selecting-specific-multiple-input-from-listquerysolution

Comment: It's possible to produce a rewindable ResultSet from the original one using:
`ResultSetMem rs = new ResultSetMem(qe.execSelect());`