# How to construct a ResultSetFormat from a List<QuerySolution>

Tags: java, jquery, parsing, format, jena

This code prints: [( ?Random = http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#Hello ), ( ?Random = http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Test#Bye )]

I need a resultsetformat so that only the part between # and > is printed. For example it should print: Hello, Bye                                                                                    How could I do that?
Thanks in advance

```
public class QuerySolutionsFromIndicesExample {

    final static String modelText = "" +
            "@prefix bio: <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Onto#>.\n" +
            "@prefix ex: <http://example.org/>.\n" +
            "\n" +
            "ex:Giraffe a bio:Animal .\n" +
            "ex:Dog a bio:Animal .\n" +
            "ex:Cat a bio:Animal . \n" +
            "ex:WoollyMammoth a bio:Animal.\n" +
            "";

    final static String sparqlQuery = "" +
            "prefix bio: <http://www.semanticweb.org/vassilis/ontologies/2013/5/Onto#>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "select ?animal where {\n" +
            "  ?animal a bio:Animal\n" +
            "}\n" +
            "";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final Model model = ModelFactory.createDefaultModel();
        model.read( new ByteArrayInputStream( modelText.getBytes()), null, "TTL" );

        final ResultSet results = ResultSetFactory.copyResults( QueryExecutionFactory.create( sparqlQuery, model ).execSelect() );

        System.out.println( "== All Solutions ==" );
        ResultSetFormatter.out( results );

       Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
                    final String inputs ;
                    inputs = input.next();

        final String[] indices = inputs.split("\\s*,\\s*");

        final List<QuerySolution> selectedSolutions = new ArrayList<QuerySolution>( indices.length ) {{
            final List<QuerySolution> solutions = ResultSetFormatter.toList( results );
            for ( final String index : indices ) {
                add( solutions.get( Integer.valueOf( index )));
            }
        }};

        System.out.println( "== Selected Solutions ==" );
        System.out.println( selectedSolutions );
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood [the suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18838995/selecting-multiple-results-from-query#comment27814034_18839492).  You'd said that you wanted to use a ResultSetFormatter to output the new results, which meant that you need to construct a ResultSet from a List<QuerySolution>, which you can then pass to a ResultSetFormatter.  Based on your answer, it sounds like you're just asking how to match a string against a regex and print the match.

Answer (score 0):

fixed it by adding this at the end of the code:

```
String s = selectedSolutions.toString();
                  String newstr;
                  newstr = s.replaceAll("_", "");



                  Pattern p = Pattern.compile("#([^>]+)>");
                   Matcher m = p.matcher(newstr);
```